# Understanding php class structure from a javascript OOP background (how to adapt code workflow)

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns

I have been attempting to write a simple RESTful api in php. Part of my goal in doing this is to get a good grasp on how to approach php OOP projects. In javascript, I have no issue with encapsulation, inheritance, etc. I generally start out with a single object (maybe even just as a namespace) that I will nest everything in, i.e.`var appName = {}`. A simpler object may just be a group of methods...then are a few typical needs like an `init` function to set things up and/or `execute/run` function in which I can detail a flow. I like to use a few general functions there that summarize everything that will happen, then detail them, then detail those, etc, so it is always easy to see how the result is produced, and you can investigate the details further as needed. I also keep everything independent so that each function doesn't have to worry about how it gets its dependencies, etc.  So, I hope that gives you an idea of where I'm coming from.. I am utterly lost in the world of oop php.

I went ahead and wrote a simple api in js just to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. It could be better, but this is just a quick example. http://jsbin.com/AmIfApO/3/edit
I have attempted for weeks to achieve this functionality in php, and have failed, failed, failed. I can make it work, but it's just awful code and I am determined to write it using best practices. For the sake of not appearing lazy, here's the latest php rewrite I tried....ended in disaster like always http://pastebin.com/cKw9YeVz.

With js, I eventually saw the right example/ got the right advice and the idea became pretty clear. I think that seeing even just the basic design flow of how this would be done in php would probably help me tie in everything I've learned. Something just hasn't clicked. If you can give me an example of what classes I should have here or how to divide things up, I would be so appreciative.

edit: to further clarify what I'm struggling with the most is just the "bones" of an application. There are so many ways to accomplish the same thing. I understand how to package things up in classes and inheritance, I just don't know how those things should be used. Here's an example of what I'm looking for. How should this look?

```
$diC = new diC(); //dependency injection container

$router = $diC->get('router');
$api = $diC->get('api'); //this class probably makes no sense

if (!$router->collection) { //api/collection - no data requested
  $data = $api->defaultResponse(); //what ought to take care of this?
}
else {
  $route = $diC->get("collection_{$router->collection}"); //instantiate the class that will handle the collection request
  $method = ($router->item) ? "{$router->verb}_item" : $router->verb; //$route->GET or $route->GET_item (for api/collection/item)
  $data = $route->$method(); //get data for the request
}

$output = $api->format($data, $router->type); //again...what should be in charge of formatting the data?

echo $output;
```

In addition to having NO clue about how the above code really ought to look, I also want to have an array of errors (`$errors = []`) that almost any part of the application can add to. I'm not sure of a clean way to make that available and get the data returned. An error class that everything is dependent on seems bad.

Comment: What don't you like about the PHP class. Help focus the question a bit?

Comment: It seems quite obvious that what you are trying to do right now is at least several month beyond your current capabilities. Make something smaller. For example, class for authentication of user.

Comment: @tereško yeah...I tend to do that. I attempt very difficult projects and fail a lot for a while. I've learned a lot over the last few days and am at least doing better. I'll post my thoughts/findings when I get closer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @SH- I updated my question with some code that demonstrates what I'm looking for. I doubt I did it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be looking to understand "PHP OOP" as this is the same as any other OOP language just with different syntax, advantages and disadvantages. You should be researching the OOP principles and how to utilise OOP effectively.

I recommend buying some OOP books and even try and learn a strongly typed language such as Java. This will stand you in good steed to use the techniques/practices learned in other languages such as PHP.

I think the problem is you feel like you are doing something wrong (by looking at your example). You should take a look at a PHP framework that will handle the database and requests for you.

These are just generic examples that outline the basic structure, take a look at this tutorial using the Laravel framework.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api/

Comment: Why did you just now link to wikipedia page about MVC and immediately prove that you did not understand it? MVC is an architectural design patter and it is not directly tied to OOP. And laravel is a framework that closely mimic Rails framework and is not even remotely associated with MVC.

Comment: I understand MVC, and I also understand its not tied. What I tried to portray was the general structure of applications that handle API requests by providing different types of examples. Perhaps I should of separated each section more clearly.

Comment: @Sam I'm having trouble seeing the need for a framework considering how VERY simple my goal is here. I updated my question with some code that demonstrates. My code will get the job done, but I want to do it well. What I did there seems better than it was before, but I really don't know.. I'm hoping someone might be able to rewrite my very simple example as it should properly look and then I can make it all work. I can't think of how to get started. I've read a ton, by the way. It's just usually so abstract.

Comment: Way down the line now, using frameworks and understanding the problems they solve and how they solve them, I now have picked up a pretty good concept of it all.